# Why my dynamically added event handler method is not firing in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, dynamic-controls

In my asp.net page codebehind, I am creating a button dynamically and adding a event handler to it. But when i set a breakpoint on the button click event (which I added in codebehind), it's not hitting. Any idea why?

My code is here

### ASP.NET PAGE

```
<form runat="Server" id="frm1">
   <div id="divPaymentOptions" runat="Server"> </div>
</form>
```

### CODEBEHIND (C#)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          LoadControl();
        }
    }
 private void LoadControl()
 {
     Button objTempBtn = new Button();
     objTempBtn.ID = "myDynamicBtn";
     objTempBtn.Text = "Clich me";
     objTempBtn.Click+=new EventHandler(objTempBtn_Click);
     this.divPaymentOptions.Controls.Add(objTempBtn);
 }

 private void objTempBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string strMsg="want to do something here";
 }
```

I put a breakpoint on divPaymentOptions. But that didn't hit when I ran it. But the postback happens when I click the button. It comes to the PageLoad method. No idea why it's not coming to my button click event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

the button doesn't exist during the postback. if you dynamically add a control to the page, you have to do it every time. take out the check for `!IsPostBack` and it should work.

Comment: then would the value remains there ? .Ex: for a textbox which i create dynamically and i want to read the value of it in a button click

Comment: the value will remain the same, no worries :)

Comment: However, I suggest that you move the control declaration to page_init

Comment: Also, it is best to add the control(Button) during the page preinit so that the Viewstate is loaded to it. That may be a reason for your problem. Here is a link about the page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx